# Increasing rails performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization

I'm finishing up my first real rails project and I'm taking some time to go back and try and increase efficiency/performance.

For instance, I have a model `Section` (simplified below) which is recursive in so much that any given section can be a parent and/or child of any other section.

**Section**

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('sections.id ASC')

  attr_accessible               :name, 
                                :parent_id

  def children(all_sections)
    # ::ORIGINAL CODE::
    # return Section.where(parent_id: id)

    # ::OPTIMIZED CODE THAT REMOVES ADDITIONAL DB CALLS::
    children = []

    all_sections.each do |sec|
      children.push(sec) if sec.parent_id == id
    end

    return children
  end
end
```

Originally, I would get all the sections, loop though them and call `children` on each section to get that specific sections children. I changed the code above so now I pass in all the sections and loop though them to get the sections children.

**footer.html.haml**

```
- @sections = Section.all

%footer
  - @sections.each do |section|
    - if section.parent_id == 0
      %nav{:id=>"#{section.name}"}
        %h1
          = section.name
        %ul
          - section.children(@sections).each do |subsection|
            %li
              = subsection.name
```

As this is the footer and is rendered on every page, I was hoping that removing additional DB calls would increase performance, and it does appear to, but not by much, maybe 5-10ms.

What I would like to know is, am I on the right track with this, and what can I do to make this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from ActiveRecord-level optimizations, have you considered caching `Section`s by timestamp? That way, you only go back to the database for a new `Section` when it has been updated (and thus expired the cache.)

[Here](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_revised/) is a good reference on caching. With HTTP caching, you don't even need to hit the Rails stack at all.

Comment: I didn't even know that was a thing (still pretty new to this). Do you have a link to a tutorial or something I could check out?

Comment: Yeah, caching is a thing. You might have missed it, but I added a link to a tutorial. Click on "Here" in my answer. If it helps you, an upvote or an accept would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is also one another option i.e. EagerLoading,

In Section model:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible               :name, 
                                :parent_id

  #Associations
  has_many :subsections, :class_name => "Section", :foreign_key => :parent_id

  #Scopes
  default_scope order('sections.id ASC')
  scope :only_parent, -> { where(:parent_id => 0) }
end
```

then in Sections Controller

```
class SectionsController
  def footer
    @sections = Section.includes(:subsections).only_parent
  end
end
```

Now in View,

```
%footer
  - @sections.each do |section|
      %nav{:id=>"#{section.name}"}
        %h1
          = section.name
        %ul
          - section.subsections.each do |subsection| #(now this will not execute any query, as this has already been eager loaded)
            %li
              = subsection.name
```